# Send already serialized message inside message

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

I'm using Protobuf with the C++ API and I have a standart message I send between 2 different softwares and I want to add a raw nested message as data.
So I added a message like this:

```
    Message main{
string id=1;
string data=2;
}
```

I tried to serialize some nested messages I made to a string and send it as "data" with "main" message but it doesn't work well on the parser side.

How can I send nested serialized message inside a message using c++ and python api.

Comment: When I've done this, I have submessages but don't double-serialize. You pack all the data in the main object and then serialize once. That's the easiest way to deal with it. Is that an option? If not let's roll up our sleeves. Also let us know if this is proto2 or proto3.

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying-field-rules: ***A string must always contain UTF-8 encoded or 7-bit ASCII text, and cannot be longer than 2^32.*** the `bytes` type is likely more appropriate since it can contain arbitrary bytes, not just 7-bit ASCII text.

Comment: Its proto3,  and it's not an option to use submessage because I want to pass the data between modules without the need to link against the message header file

Answer (score 2):

Basically, use `bytes`:

```proto
message main {
    string id=1;
    bytes data=2;
}
```

In addition to not corrupting the data (`string` is strictly UTF-8), as long as the payload is a standard message, this is also compatible with changing it later (at either end, or both) to the known type:

````proto
``` proto
message main {
    string id=1;
    TheOtherMessageType data=2;
}
message TheOtherMessageType  {...}
````

(or even using both versions at different times depending on which is most convenient)

Comment: But how do you serialize the message? Using SerializeToArray()?

Comment: @Zach serialize the enclosed message or serialize the enclosing message? The process is the same for both.